# Python: using argparse,Pass , read and change html file in a class , also with pass dictionary and list using argparse via CL

Tags: python, html, dictionary, argparse

I am trying to pass a file and read it and change its contents using argparse. I am passing some dictionaries and a list as well. It is not working. 
This is the error I am getting:

```
$ python practice.py templateP.html '{"title":"TEST"}' ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice.py", line 33, in <module>
    one = Core(args)
  File "practice.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.title = args.title
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'title'
```

The dictionary and lists are for example:

```
 title1 = {'title':'TEST'}
ouritems = ['ITEM1','ITEM2','ITEM3']
```

This is the contents of the html file: named as templateP.html

```
<html> 

<meta> 

    <title tal:content="context.title" /> 

    <body  > 

        <div tal:condition="items"> 

             <p>These are your items:</p> 

             <ul> 

                  <li tal:repeat="item items" tal:content="item" /> 

             </ul>             

        </div> 

     </body> 

</html>
```

This is the code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import argparse
    import os.path
    from chameleon import PageTemplateLoader
    from chameleon import PageTemplate
    import json

    class Core:

    def __init__(self,args):
        self.templatestr = args.Sfile
        self.title = args.title
        self.item = args.ouritems

    def __call__(self,args):
        self.pagetemplate =  PageTemplate(args.Sfile)
        return self.pagetemplate.render(context = args.title, item = args.ouritems )



parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='template to html book cover')
parser.add_argument( 'Sfile', help="input html template file", type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('Title', help='Dictionary:Title of the book cover', type=json.loads )
parser.add_argument('ouritems', help='list of items at the back cover', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
templatestr = args.Sfile.readlines()
one = Core(args)
newTemplate = one.__call__(args)
print(newTemplate)
```

If someone have any idea what is wrong here and how can it run,I will really appreciate it.

This is the new error I am getting after adding the print(args) and changing Title.

```
$ python practice.py templateP.html '{"title":"TEST"}' [ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM2]
Namespace(Sfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='templateP.html' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>, Title={'title': 'TEST'}, ouritems=['[ITEM1', 'ITEM2', 'ITEM2]'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice.py", line 31, in <module>
    newTemplate = one.__call__(args)
  File "practice.py", line 18, in __call__
    self.pagetemplate =  PageTemplate(args.Sfile)
  File "/home/aqsa/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chameleon/zpt/template.py", line 202, in __init__
    super(PageTemplate, self).__init__(body, **config)
  File "/home/aqsa/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chameleon/template.py", line 132, in __init__
    self.write(body)
  File "/home/aqsa/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chameleon/template.py", line 221, in write
    content_type = body.startswith('<?xml')
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: Not a clue.  You say it's not working, but have told us anything about the failure.  You talk vaguely about trying other things, again without any details.  There's not even a hint as to where the failure occurs!

Comment: I have edited my post and added the error message and also for ease, i have shortened the code. I hope now you can have the idea what I am asking @hpaulj

Comment: use `args.Title`.  That's the name you gave that attribute in `add_argument`.  I recommend a `print(args)` during debugging so you see exactly what the parser has produced.

Comment: @hpaulj I have done both of that but now there are more errors. I am editing my post and adding the error I am encountering now because it is too long to fit in comment.

Comment: `args.Sfile` is an open file, what the error calls a `TextIOWrapper`.  I'm guessing `PageTemplate` expects a string (which would have a `startswith` method).  When you get an `AttributeError`, there's a mismatch between what the code expects an object to be, and what it actually is.  You have to provide `PageTemplate` with the kind of input it expects.